# How to copy the contents of a label in Base clearcase VOB?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

We want all label contents of Base Clearcase VOB. 
I created a View for the VOB and edited the **config.spec** document as

```
element * checkedout
element * label_ID
element * /main/latest
```

But it brings all the components associated with the VOB and not with the label.

How to select *only* the elements which are labelled `label_ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind seeing a load of empty directories, you can do something like this:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element -file * label_ID
element -directory * /main/LATEST
```

This will return the LATEST or CHECKEDOUT version of every folder, but it won't display a file unless it's labelled or CHECKEDOUT

Check out [the config_specs reference page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/config_spec.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-6-2) - there's a load of stuff you can do with config specs (for instance if you only wanted the MSWord documentation, you could so "element -file *.doc /main/LATEST")

Comment: Thanks @VonC for your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If the label has been set on the vob itself, and on all elements (for instance: `/<vobtab>/dir1`, `/<vobtab>/dir1/dir2/`, `/<vobtab>/dir1/dir2/*`), *then* the following config spec would only bring the labelled elements, and not the rest of the vob elements:

```
element * checkedout
element * label_ID
element * -none
```

But if label_ID has been set on all elements within `/<vobtab>/dir1/dir2/*`, *and not* on `/<vobtab>/dir1/` (the parent folder itself) or not on `/<vobtab>/` (the root folder of the vob itself), then that config spec would bring no elements at all.
A workaround would be to select the parent elements:

```
element * checkedout
element * label_ID
element /<vob_tag>/dir1 /main/LATEST
element /<vob_tag> /main/LATEST
element * -none
```

I would recommend doing this in a dynamic view (which can be refreshed very quickly after each config spec modification), instead of a snapshot view (which has to reload after each `setcs`)

---

**Another approach, not based on a config spec** (since it can be difficult to select the right parent folders in order to access the labelled elements) is to use a [`cleartool find`](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-14) query.
See:

- "[ClearCase list of files with given label type applied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289973/6309)"
- "[ClearCase: Find files having exactly one specific label and not more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1037829/6309)"
- "[How to search files by label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2221254/6309)":

Basically, you can *list* only the labelled element by going into your 'preferably dynamic) view and doing:

> UNIX and Linux:

```
cleartool find -cview -element '{lbtype_sub(REL1)}' -print
```

> Windows:

```
cleartool find -cview -element "{lbtype_sub(REL1)}" -print
```

Instead of using `-print`, you can use `-exec "a command"`, and use the exec option to execute any command, like copying what you just found:

```
cleartool find -cview -element "{lbtype_sub(REL1)}" -exec "copy \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" c:\a\path"

cleartool find . –version "lbtype(LB_TYPE)"
```

---

If the command is too finicky, simply redirect the result to a file:

```
cleartool find -cview -element "{lbtype_sub(REL1)}" -print > file.txt
```

Then process that file to copy its content, as in "[Batch: Copy a list (txt) of files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258198/6309)":

```
@echo off
set src_folder=c:\whatever
set dst_folder=c:\target
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (File-list.txt) DO (
    xcopy /S/E/U "%src_folder%\%%i" "%dst_folder%"
)
```

Comment: still i'm not able to get the result after using that command,please provide the exact command and how it works,this is the error i'm facing after running this command.              **M:\Race_Label\RACE>cleartool find -all -element "{lbtype_sub(BUILD_RACE_HFM_01)}" -exec "copy \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" C:\111"  **



'cleartool: Error: Can't exec "copy "M:\Race_Label\RACE\HFM\Application Profile\RACE Profile.per" C:\111": The system cannot find the file specified.'@VonC

Comment: @CCUSER simply remove the `-all`, or replace it with `-cview`: that will limit the result to the labelled elements which are actually visible (and can be copied) as opposed to "all" versions which can reference elements since deleted (rmname).

Comment: M:\Race_Label\RACE>**cleartool find -cview -element "{lbtype_sub(BUILD_RACE_HFM_01
)}" -exec "copy \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" > C:\111\" **
cleartool: Error: Pathname required.
Usage: find { pname ... [-depth | -nrecurse | -directory]
            | [pname ...] -all [-visible | -nvisible]
            | -avobs [-visible | -nvisible]
            }
            [-name 'pattern']
            [-cview
            [-type {f|d|l}...]
           
   
       
            {-print | -exec command-invocation | -ok command-invocation}        it is asking the path please read the error message@VonC

Comment: @CCUSER why do you have a '`>`' between `\"%CLEARCASE_PN%\"`  and `C:\111\"`? Could you try without `>`? Also C:\111 should end with a `"`, not a '\"`.

Comment: I Ran : cleartool find -cview -element "{lbtype_sub(BUILD_RACE_HFM_01
)}" -exec **"copy \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" C:\a"**
I got error as : **cleartool: Error: Pathname required.**
I have tried all the posssibilities with this command, please provide your valuable suggestions in this.

Comment: @CCUSER maybe a different approach is required if the exec part if too tricky to setup right: you could use first a `-print` (instead of the `-exec`) to at least check that it does list the files that you expect. Then you can redirect that output in a file: `cleartool find ... -print > afile`, and feed that file to a little script like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6258198/6309

Comment: @CCUSER Strange: your first error messages show that the `find` command would find at least one file. Try to make the `find -print` work first.

Comment: the script is giving trouble

Comment: @CCUSER do you mean the script I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6258198/6309? First, does the `cleartool find ... -print` work properly? Do you have the list of files you expect?